# web scraping with Python and displaying data on React app

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping

I have learnt how to web scrape with python and create react apps, I'm wondering what the general way would be if I wanted to web scrape data with python display that data on a react app if possible?

Comment: I think this question is much too broad for StackOverflow. I have a related blog post on [Creating Search Engine for any Website using Web Scraping](https://scrapfly.io/blog/search-engine-using-web-scraping/) which uses Lunrjs to display and query scrapped data - maybe you could integrate it with your react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have scraped images with python on the backend and react.js on the frontend.
What I did was to get the URLs of thousands of images and save them in json file and send it to the react part